# jQuery issue with the reservation form

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

I need some help to create a jquery script that will handle the car reservation form.

The form have fields such as the “Start date, End date (in datepicker), localization (city) of rent and return the car with  the list of direction and the number of days for which the customer borrowed car. There is only one dependency. If the car is rented for less than 4 days the city of borrowing and returning is the same, and if the number of days are greater than 4 days locations of returning car may be different.

The whole form works pretty well, to the point where client chose the city and the number of days is less than 4. The value of first City is “copying” to the second City field (and other values of city are disabled), and that is correct. Under the first city appear the field with directions, but under second city the list of direction not showing (but should, because the city is selected).

When I change the date and the values of total day is greater then 4 and in second field all of city are active and if I select one of them the directions are showing up, and that is ok, but I have to “click” the City. When it is inserting by the script the list of direction are disabled.

Could anyone help me with this?

The workin example: http://jsfiddle.net/amarcinkowski/EbdFY/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the first, you duplicate your bindings of change event on `#return_car` and `#get_car`. Delete or comment this rows:

```
$('select#return_car').change(compute);
$('select#get_car').change(compute);
```

At the second, as Maxime L writes:

```
if ( parseInt($("#finish_day").val()) < 4 ) {
  $('#return_car')
    .children('#return_car option[value=' + $('#get_car').val() + ']')
    .attr('selected', true)
    .siblings().attr('disabled', true);
  if ($('#return_car').val()) $('#return_car').change(); // or $('#return_car').trigger('change');
}
```

Comment: Hi @Kir - it work pretty well, but I noticed a problem with datepicker - it don't hidden after i click a day, and when I delete `#return_car` and `#get_car` the city from first box don't copy to the second box if the total day is less than 4

Comment: In this case remove or comment only `$('select#return_car').change(compute);`. But you must always remember that you have two bindings on `#get_car`

Comment: You are right! One more thing - under the city2 the script display the same values as under the city1 box - it should display only 3 options and now showing 4 options

Comment: Datepicker don't close because an error occurs. There are two possible reasons: if you place `$('#return_car').change();` without `if ($('#return_car').val())` or if `$('select#return_car').change(compute);` is not deleted or commented :)

Comment: In the under the city1 box now are 4 options

Comment: Thanks @Kir once again - You Rock Man! :)

Comment: I have one more problem with this part of code `if ($('#return_car').val()) $('#return_car').change();`- I can't validate it :(

Comment: Show please feedle with the last variant

Comment: The form working on special app who validate each field. If I click the "second" city app validate it, but when it is selected by script the validator return the error.

Comment: Is validator JS script? And as variant you can try this: `$('#return_car').children(...).attr('selected', 'selected') ...`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/14793/discussion-between-adrian-and-kir)

Comment: I actually try with this - and this dosn't help. And No - it isn't validate by JS, and one more thing - when I delete the `if ($('#return_car').val()) $('#return_car').change();` code - the validator is working fine.

Answer (score 1):

You could "force" the change event to execute with

```
$('#return_car').change()
```

And the direction input will be shown.

Comment: In this case in your script infinite recursion

Comment: It worked for me, I tested it to be sure before submitting my answer. Add it after ".siblings().attr('disabled', true);"

Oh, and I forgot ";" !

Comment: I insert code in wrong place... I noticed that after that change in code the second part of form working very slow and if total day is less than 4 date2 didn't hide after mouse out